# Why does Chrome interact differently with a mounted Android file system on Windows10?

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, upload, windows-10

I have a web app with a file upload form that works fine with every combination of browser/file system except Chrome reading from a mounted Android or iOS device (HFS and DCF file systems). Using a 3rd-party jQuery event handler (ajaxupload), it reads the filename from HTMLInputElement.value for a simple file extension check before uploading.

The different strings I'm seeing are:
IE/Android: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\DAG5BXZ2\filename.jpg"
Edge/Android: "filename.jpg"
Firefox/Android: "C:\fakepath\filename.jpg"
Chrome/USBDrive: "C:\fakepath\filename.jpg"
Chrome/Android: "C:\fakepath\{C8BCC7E6-C108-D148-F5FF-3BC3EB92E793}"

How/why is Chrome handling these file systems different than the others? Is there any way to change it or work around it? All I need is the file extension.

Update: It appears that Chrome is trying to operate on a temporary path/file it has created but which is not valid. The FileList object is valid and I can access file[0] - it has a .name (the UUID string), a .lastmodifieddate (when the user clicked 'Open' - not the actual file's date), .size is 0, and .type is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: This was a bug in Chrome that was introduced by modifications to the filepicker to allow uploading remote files. It was fixed sometime during March, 2019.